# Having an error while trying to open TensorBoard in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard

ERROR: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with 1).

```
Contents of stderr:<br />
Traceback (most recent call last):<br />
  File "c:\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main<br />
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,<br />
  File "c:\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code<br />
    exec(code, run_globals)<br />
  File "C:\Python38\Scripts\tensorboard.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module><br />
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 43, in <module><br />
    from tensorboard import default<br />
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\default.py", line 39, in <module><br />
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio import audio_plugin<br />
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\audio\audio_plugin.py", line 28, in <module><br />
    from tensorboard.data import provider<br />
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\data\__init__.py", line 20, in <module><br />
    from tensorboard.data import experimental<br />
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\data\experimental\__init__.py", line 20, in <module><br />
    from tensorboard.data.experimental.experiment_from_dev import ExperimentFromDev<br />
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\data\experimental\experiment_from_dev.py", line 25, in <module><br />
    import grpc<br />
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grpc'<br />
```

I have tried running "pip install grpc" but it cannot find a module with that name. For some background info, I don't have an Nvidia GPU, in case that matters.

EDIT: "python -m pip install grpcio" solved my issue. However, I now have a new error.

```
ERROR: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with 1).
Contents of stderr:
2020-06-24 11:42:16.160102: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-06-24 11:42:16.166831: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python38\Scripts\tensorboard.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 75, in run_main
    app.run(tensorboard.main, flags_parser=tensorboard.configure)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 290, in main
    return runner(self.flags) or 0
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 306, in _run_serve_subcommand
    server = self._make_server()
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 411, in _make_server
    app = application.TensorBoardWSGIApp(
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 128, in TensorBoardWSGIApp
    return TensorBoardWSGI(
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\backend\application.py", line 225, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Duplicate plugins for name projector
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

`python -m pip install grpcio`

and potentially

`python -m pip install grpcio-tools`

[website](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/)